# Concatenate an array of hours into a friendly string

Tags: php, time

Anybody have any shortcuts to this:

I have an array of hours, say something like this:

```
$hours = array(4,5,6,9,10,14);
```

I want to convert that to a pretty string, in this sort of format:

```
$ret = '4am-7am; 9am-11am; 2pm-3pm';
```

This is an array of clock hours on a 24-hour clock. The 4 in the array represents 0400 hours (4am). The 14 is 1400 hours (2pm). I expect the rest are self explanatory. There are multiple breaks, so 7AM and 8AM are not included in the array. Because these are clock hours, these are trailing edge inclusive... since 6AM is specified, that includes the entire hour of 6AM, which ends at 6:59 AM. From a user point of view, this really means 7AM. I can draw a picture if that helps

Anybody got any handy shortcuts?  : )

Comment: It is not clear how the intervals like `4am-7am` are formed. Where did `7am` came from?

Comment: These are clock hours.  Imagine, from such a perspective, that it is really 6:59am.  For my purposes, though, 'to 7am' makes the most sense.

Comment: @chapagain How can I be more clear, then? : )

Comment: buddy I mean Mr.Green they need to know why and how you get 4am and 7am together, and why 9am and 11am. I mean at least I wanna know that.

Comment: Please specify the condition more clearly. You have array(4,5,6,9,10,14). What is the condition to print 4am-7am; 9am-11am?

Comment: Edited my response to provide further info.  Thanks @BurnAfterReading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not very pretty, but here is the solution I came up with:  Happy to hear if somebody has a cleaner solution.  : )

```
function formatHour($hour){
    $pNormalizedHour = $hour % 12;
    $pNormalizedHour = ($pNormalizedHour == 0) ? 12 : $pNormalizedHour;
    return  $pNormalizedHour.($hour < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm');
}
function timeArrToFriendly($hours){
   // cache this, since we'll be asking for it potentially dozens of times.
   $pArrCount = count($hours);
   $retVal = '';
   for ($i=0; $i < $pArrCount; $i++)
   {
       $retVal .= ($retVal == '') ? '' : '; ';
       $retVal .= formatHour($hours[$i]);
       if (($i >= $pArrCount-1) || (($hours[$i + 1]) != ($hours[$i] + 1))){
          $retVal .= '-'.formatHour($hours[$i] + 1);
          continue;         
       }
       for ($j = $i+1; $j < $pArrCount; $j++){
           if (($j >= $pArrCount-1) || ($hours[$j + 1] != $hours[$j] + 1)){
               $retVal .= '-'.formatHour($hours[$j] +1);
               $i = $j;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   return $retVal;
}
// test string.  Correct output:
//  => 4am-7am; 9am-11am; 12pm-1pm; 2pm-3pm; 6pm-10pm
$hours = array(4,5,6,9,10,12,14,18,19,20,21);
echo timeArrToFriendly($hours);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work a treat. Only about 4 lines.  I dont' think you can do each much easier due to the "am", "pm" and the %12

```
<?php
$hours = array(4,5,6,9,10,14);
$time = "";
for($i=0, $j=1; $i<count($hours); $i+=2, $j+=2){        
    $suffix1 = $hours[$i] <12?"am":"pm";   
    $suffix2 = $hours[$j] <12?"am":"pm";
    $time .= $hours[$i].$suffix1."-".($hours[$j]%12).$suffix2."; ";   
}
print $time."\n";
?>
```

Comment: this outputs         4am-5am; 6am-9am; 10am-2pm;

Comment: Looks awesome. Didn't even realize you could this.  However, it has the wrong answer.  Should be:  '4am-7am; 9am-11am; 2pm-3pm';  I think it needs to do a break detection.

Comment: I finally see what you are doing... Ops, that was not a very well asked question, grrrr....

Comment: I dunno... seems like it was a hard question to ask.  In my defense, I did put the answer up in my initial post.  : )

Comment: Btw, thanks for taking a stab at it. +1, for that, and because looking at your solution did fire up the brain a bit so that I could derive what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the 1. Thats the hardest 1 I have ever worked for.  I did look at you answer to think if I could do it in less code. But then realized I actual have some other things to solve : )